# generic compare function for 2 class types

Tags: delphi, generics

here come my definition of Vertex class and graph class using generic programming features of Delphi :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  System.Math, System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  tvertex = class(TObject)
    name: string;
    function markme: tvertex;
    function Compare(const v: TVertex): Integer;
    constructor create;
    destructor free;
  end;

  tvertex<T> = class(tvertex)
    Userdata: T;
  end;

  TGraph <T : class > = class (Tobject)
      vertexlist :  TObjectList<T>;

      procedure CompareLists(
      var _V1: TObjectList<T>;
      var _V2: TObjectList<T>);
  end;




  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

  // helper function
function createVertexComparer(): IComparer <TVertex  >;

implementation

// helper functions
function createVertexComparer(): IComparer<TVertex>;
begin
  Result := TDelegatedComparer<TVertex>.Create(
    function(const Left, Right: TVertex): Integer
    begin
      Result := Left.Compare(Right);
    end);

end;




{$R *.dfm}
{ tvertex }

function tvertex.Compare(const v: TVertex): Integer;
begin
    // ...
end;

constructor tvertex.create;
begin
  // ...
end;

destructor tvertex.free;
begin
  // ...
end;

function tvertex.markme: tvertex;
begin
  // ...
end;



procedure TGraph<T>.CompareLists(
var _V1: TObjectList<T>;
var _V2: TObjectList<T>);
begin
     _V1 := TObjectList<T>.Create(createVertexComparer(), False);  /// line which does not compile ....
end;

end.
```

How to modify the code that he is willing to accept `TVertex` and `TVertex<T>`  class types as arguments ....

Comment: Please describe what you really want with that `TGraph` class. Do you want to fill some vertices and let `TGraph` paint them somewhere with a method `TGraph.Paint` and now you get stuck, how to handle all the generic vertices inside this method?

Comment: Which method are you having problems with? Which method does not accept both `TVertex` and `TVertex<T>`. Could you give us an SSCCE? So not a GUI app. A single complete console app.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message? Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: the comoiler error is [DCC Fehler] Unit1.pas(98): E2250 Es gibt keine überladene Version von 'Create', die man mit diesen Argumenten aufrufen kann  ( no overloaded version)

Comment: funny, one can open http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/E2250_No_base_class_to_initialize_(C%2B%2B) but not docwiki page on another e2250 class

Comment: Repeating Joachim Marder, *What is the exact compiler error message?* **Which Delphi version are you using?** //  "[DCC Fehler] Unit1.pas(98)" - which line is 98 ? please, edit the source to show the error exactly where it is generated. Also while editing your question, add a tag with your delphi version below the question, thank you.

Comment: OK  : I'm using DELPHI XE 2 and the error line is V1 := TObjectList<T>.Create(createVertexComparer(), False); there is no overloaded verion of the compare function. Instead of overloading , means writing for each possible vertex type a compare function i though I could make the compare function also generic and therefor accept arbitrary  generic class types.

Comment: @ sir rufo : TVertex should be the naked representation of a vertex in a graph. All Tgraph procedures, functions basically only need the TVertex as an data type.   TVertex<T> will additionally also hold use case depending data eg. for painting the graph or data which will be used to build the graph structure.  Based on this different meaning I would also separate between Tvertex and Tvertex<T>   ....

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the main problem that you have is that you declared the graph class like this:

```
type
  TGraph<T: class>
    ...
  end;
```

And this means that the compiler will accept any class as `T`. Consequently the graph class knows nothing about `T`, beyond that it is a class.

It's hard to be sure, but I think that you intend `T` to be a vertex. So you need to constraint the graph class appropriately.

```
type
  TGraph<T: TVertex>
    ...
  end;
```

And then you have another problem with this function:

```
function createVertexComparer(): IComparer<TVertex>;
```

You pass the result of that to

```
TObjectList<T>.Create
```

But that expects a parameter of type `IComparer<T>` and you are supplying `IComparer<TVertex>`. That's the type mismatch that the compiler reports.

You'll need to make `createVertexComparer` be a method of `TGraph<T>` so that it can be generic. Its implementation would be:

```
function TGraph<T>.createVertexComparer(): IComparer<T>;
begin
  Result := TDelegatedComparer<T>.Create(
    function(const Left, Right: T): Integer
    begin
      Result := Left.Compare(Right);
    end);
end;
```

---

Also, do note that

```
destructor free;
```

is a disaster waiting to happen. You must use

```
destructor Destroy; override;
```

In fact, the rest of your code troubles me. For instance:

```
procedure TGraph<T>.CompareLists(var _V1, _V2: TObjectList<T>);
begin
  _V1 := TObjectList<T>.Create(createVertexComparer(), False);
end;
```

The method's name does not match what it does. It only returns one value, so why have two `var` parameters? It's very hard to discern intent when viewing code like this.

Comment: Understand that my coding approach is very dangerous, will rethink all my activities  and  ....  Anyhow your answers are very helpful and exactly meet my coding problem

Comment: Am I right in my believe that the `T` in `TGraph<T>` is meant to be a vertex?

Comment: In that case the changes I outline should be what you need.